# How to run multiple commands in docker-compose for a windows container?

Tags: docker, batch-file, docker-compose

I'd like to run multiple commands within a docker-compose.yml for a windows-service like this:

```yaml
    entrypoint: ["cmd", "/C"]
    command:  > 
      echo Hello
      echo World
```

or this:

```yaml
command: cmd /C "
        echo Hello 
        echo World
      "
```

which outputs:

```
Hello echo World
```

and not

```
Hello 
World
```

Comment: Well multiple commands should be seperated with ampersands: ```cmd /C "echo Hello& echo World"```.

Comment: @Compo Thx, if you put this as answer I mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Compo has put me in the right direction:

```yaml
command:  cmd /C "
      echo Hello && 
      echo World &
      echo Caffeee
      "
```

One `&` is for only sequentiell chaining and two `&&` is for additional error checking which in this case of `echo`-command makes no sense.